# How to user redirect when app is background or terminated?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Flutter Firebase push notifications on my Flutter project. But when the user taps on the notification I redirect the user to my home chat screen. It works properly when my app is open. But When my app is going to Background or Terminated the user does not redirect my home chat screen when taps to open my splash screen.

There is the code I am using and this function I am calling in my home chat screen. In my main.dart file I use a flutter background service.

main.dart code

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(const MyApp());

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}
```

```
Future<void> setupInteractMessage(BuildContext context) async {
    //when app is terminated.
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      handleMessage(context, initialMessage);
    }

    //when app in background.
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((event) {
      handleMessage(context, event);
    });
  }

  void handleMessage(BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'msg') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
        MyHome.routeName, (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
      );
    }
  }
```